# Returning different values based on selected data

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that selects a row based on an id (simple enough), but only returns the actual result if the data satisfies a few conditions, otherwise it returns specific error codes. So when doing nested checks, the code would look similiar to this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetStuffById
@StuffId int
AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Stuff] WHERE StuffId = @StuffId)
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @IsValid bit
    SET @IsValid = (SELECT IsValid FROM [Stuff] WHERE StuffId = @StuffId)
    IF @IsValid = 1
        BEGIN
        --More nested checks may occur here
        SELECT * FROM [Stuff] WHERE StuffId = @StuffId
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        RETURN -2
        END
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
    RETURN -1
    END
END
```

In this approach I already have 3 selects on the same table, which seems redundant and inefficient and another check would mean another select etc. Is there a better pattern to do this (e.g. temp tables)?

UPDATE: edited first check

Comment: Why do you need to distinguish between empty table and no matching row? Do the other checks all use values from that row?

Comment: You could use sql "CASE ..... END CASE" statements in one query but that depends..

Comment: @MartinSmith My bad, left out the where clause, fixed now. And yes, all checks should run on the same row (provided it exists), but every check should return a different errorcode.

Comment: I agree with @Vijay and would like to know the answer to  Martin Smith. What type of client are you using? Is it a .NET application?

Comment: Client is of yet undecided, it's for a third party app (not a .NET app), which might or might not use .NET connector. Anyway Martin's answer seems to be the way, but it would be nice if you could provide an example for the 'CASE' version (I know about that SQL statement, I just don't know how it could be applied in this situation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign to multiple variables in a single select and use `@@ROWCOUNT` to detect whether a row was found.

```
DECLARE @IsValid BIT,
        @Foo     INT

SELECT @IsValid = IsValid,
       @Foo = Foo
FROM   [Stuff]
WHERE  StuffId = @StuffId

/*This must be tested immediately after the assignment statement*/
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
  RETURN -1

IF ISNULL(@IsValid, 0) = 0
  RETURN -2

SELECT @IsValid AS IsValid,
       @Foo     AS Foo
```